# Can given dices make the given string?

Tags: python, recursion

I was trying to see if the given dices can make up given string. Take this particular case in which if we are given `'IAM'` and

```
given_set= [['I', 'B', 'A'], ['J', 'I', 'P',], ['M', 'R', 'S'], ['T', 'U', 'V']]
```

My code returns False for this. But if we grab `'I'` from second list and `'A'` from first list we can still make the string. I think I covered up most of other cases besides this one.

Can anyone direct on how I can address this particular case?

Here is my code:

```
def possible(string, given_set):
    a = False

    if len(string) > len(given_set):
        return False

    if string == '':
        return True

    for i in string:

        for index, value in enumerate(given_set):

            if i in value:
                a = possible(string[1:],given_set[0:index] + given_set[index+1:])
                return a
            else:
                return False
```

Comment: if you are going to make it a recursive implementation, remove `for i in string` and only work on the first character of string

Comment: It looks like the problem is you're finding "I" in the first set, then trying to find "AM" in the last three sets, which is false, which comes back into the variable `a`, and you return False. You need to keep going at that point, because in this case you need "I" from the second set. Only return if it's True.

Comment: @JordanTrudgett I kind of followed what you said. I have added my solution in the answer. Do you think it is ok?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the calls being made:

```
possible('IAM',[['I', 'B', 'A'], ['J', 'I', 'P'], ['M', 'R', 'S'], ['T', 'U', 'V']])
possible('AM',[['J', 'I', 'P'], ['M', 'R', 'S'], ['T', 'U', 'V']])
```

you will see that it returns `False` because it will use the set containing both `'I'` and `'A'`, so it will not possible at the second iteration to find a set containing `'A'`.

Turn it into a generator, so it is possible to explore all the possible solutions (i.e. backtrack), and it will work:

```
def possible(string, given_set):
    if len(string) > len(given_set):
        return

    if string == '':
        yield True
        return

    for index, value in enumerate(given_set):
        if string[0] in value:
            yield from possible(string[1:], given_set[0:index] + given_set[index+1:])
```

You would use `any()` for checking if it is possible to make a string with the dices:

```
>>> print(any(possible('IAM',given_set)))
True

>>> print(any(possible('IAB',given_set)))
False
```

Note: `yield from ...` requires Python 3.4+. In previous verisons you can write `for x in ...: yield x`

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you don't return `False` too quickly because you can still try other possibilities. Here, you'll see we only return `a` if it is `True` - because once you've found a solution, there's no need to keep looking, you can just return `True` straight away. That `True` will be returned all the way back through the recursive calls.

You also had `return False` if `i` was not in `value` - that means you give up if it's not in the first set you look at, which is also wrong. I've moved that return to outside the loop, because you only know it's not possible once you've looked at all the sets:

```
def possible(string, given_set):
    a = False

    if len(string) > len(given_set):
        return False

    if string == '':
        return True

    for i in string:

        for index, value in enumerate(given_set):
            if i in value:
                a = possible(string[1:],given_set[0:index] + given_set[index+1:])
                if a:
                    return a
        return False
```

Now I believe it works:

```
given_set= [['I', 'B', 'A'], ['J', 'I', 'P',], ['M', 'R', 'S'], ['T', 'U', 'V']]

# possible cases
print possible("IJM", given_set) # True
print possible("IJT", given_set) # True
print possible("IIM", given_set) # True
print possible("JMT", given_set) # True
print possible("IMA", given_set) # True
print possible("VIB", given_set) # True
print possible("VPA", given_set) # True

# impossible cases
print possible("ZZZ", given_set) # False
print possible("ABC", given_set) # False
print possible("AIJ", given_set) # False
print possible("IJB", given_set) # False
print possible("VPT", given_set) # False
print possible("JRP", given_set) # False
print possible("RAS", given_set) # False
```